# How to handle duplicate values using LARGE() function?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate the top 3 results with duplicate values but different names.

Example data:

```
Name           score
A              40
B              55
C              37
D              55
```

Expected result:

```
order        score     name
1            55        B
1            55        D
3            40        A
```

Comment: Please format your question so it is understandable. Use the CODE block for entering a table. And show your expected results and what you have already tried.

Comment: You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: FYI I've just updated my answer to show how to randomise the order of names for identical scores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a pivot table, as well as the `RANK()` function.

### Step 1 - Preparing the Pivot Table

1. Add a column (e.g. in C) to your data, with the following formula: `=RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$5)` -> this will display how `B2` ranks among all values in `$B$2:$B$5`

[image]

2. Select your data (including the rank column) and click Insert > Pivot Table
3. Put the fields "Score" and "Name" as rows, and the field "Score" as values as shown

[image]

4. Format the pivot table by clicking the following menu items:

[image]

You should now have something similar to this:

[image]

---

### Step 2 - Displaying the top 3 values (Method A)

1. Click on the arrow near the first field of your pivot table (Rank)
2. Select "Value Filters"
3. Select "Top 10"

[image]

4. Enter `3` instead of `10` to have the top 3 values

[image]

You should now have something like this:

[image]

**Note:** with this method, if several values have the same rank (like in your example data), they will be shown multiple times. That's the default behaviour of the pivot table and the "Top X" features.

If you don't want 4 lines, but only 3, see method B

---

### Step 2 - Displaying the top 3 values (Method B)

1. Click on the arrow near the first field of your pivot table (Rank)
2. Select "Label Filters"
3. Select "Less than or equal to", and enter `3` when prompted

[image]

**Note:** be careful with this method: if there are 5 values with rank 1, there will be 5 lines. The 2nd highest value will then have rank 6, and will not be displayed (it's greater than 3). So it's not really a top 3 anymore, but I think this method is worth mentioning, as in some cases it might work.

---

When the data changes, don't forget to refresh the pivot table!

Comment: I hope it will work exactly as i need!
 thanks alot! 
 May Allah bless you and your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with just two simple formulas for the `order` and `score` columns, plus a third, slightly more complicated one, for the `name` column.

Set up a spreadsheet like the following:

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Then multi-cell array-enter these formulas into the specified ranges (remembering to exclude the surrounding `{` and `}`):

**Formula 1** (`D2:D4`):

```dart
{=RANK(E2:E4,E2:E4)}
```

**Formula 2** (`E2:E4`):

```dart
{=LARGE(B2:B5,{1;2;3})}
```

**Formula 3** (`F2:F4`):

```dart
{=INDEX(A:A,10^5-MOD(LARGE(10^5*B2:B5+10^5-ROW(B2:B5),{1;2;3}),10^5))}
```

---

To change from the top 3 results to the top N results where N is a largish number, say `10`, for example, instead of using a hard-coded array for the ranks, `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}`, use the following:

```dart
ROW(INDEX(X:X,1):INDEX(X:X,10))
```

While this works as is, it is preferable to replace `X:X` with the column that the formula is entered in. That way the formula won't break if column `X` is deleted.

This is a much better solution than the ubiquitous and shorter `ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))` as it is non-volatile.

---

**Formula Explanations:**

The first two formulas are straightforward enough.

The prettified version of the third formula is as follows:

```dart
=
INDEX(
  (A:A),
  10^5-
  MOD(
    LARGE(
      10^5*B2:B5+10^5-ROW(B2:B5),
      {1;2;3}
    ),
    10^5
  )
)
```

The formula works by modifying the scores so that they also contain the ten's complement of the row index. Then, after `LARGE` selects the appropriate modified score, the index is extracted and used with `INDEX()` to obtain the name corresponding to the selected score.

Stepping through the formula in `F3` should make the above clearer:

- `10^5*B2:B5`
  → `10^5*{40;55;37;55}`
  → `{4000000;5500000;3700000;5500000}`, the scaled scores
- `10^5-ROW(B2:B5)`
  → `10^5-{2;3;4;5}`
  → `{99998;99997;99996;99995}`, the ten's complement of the row numbers of the scores
- `{4000000;5500000;3700000;5500000}+{99998;99997;99996;99995}`
  → `{4099998;5599997;3799996;5599995}`, the "modified" scores
- `LARGE({4099998;5599997;3799996;5599995},{1;2;3})`
  → `{5599997;5599995;4099998}`, the top three modified scores
- `10^5-MOD({5599997;5599995;4099998},10^5)`
  → `10^5-{99997;99995;99998}`
  → `{3;5;2}`, the row numbers of the top three scores
- `INDEX(A:A,{3;5;2})`
  → `{B;D;A}`
  → `D` since we are in in the second cell of the multi-cell array-entered formula

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `(A:A)` are required to force the `A:A` to remain on its own line.
- For identical scores, the formula returns the names in ascending row order. The formula can be modified to return the names in descending order by using the plain row number instead of the ten's complement of the row number when modifying the scores:

```dart
{=INDEX(A:A,MOD(LARGE(10^5*B2:B5+ROW(B2:B5),{1;2;3}),10^5))}
```

- It is even possible to randomise the order of identical scores by generating a modified score with a random number between the score and the row number.

Comment: HEY sir...the index formula {=INDEX(A:A,MOD(LARGE(10^5*B2:B5+ROW(B2:B5),{1;2;3}),10^5))}
 Is not working! it gives me a blank cell but when i click on it the formula displays on the formula bar.
 I press Ctrl +shift + enter.
 The pivot table works. Thanks alot
 But i am interested on the index formula....i need ur help

Comment: @Dimah Sorry. The `{` and the `}` is just there to remind you that the formula has to be array-entered. You need to not copy them or remove them when you paste the formula. So, with cells `B2:B5` selected and `B2` active, enter `=INDEX(A:A,10^5-MOD(LARGE(10^5*B2:B5+10^5-ROW(B2:B5),{1;2;3}),10^5))` into `B2` and then press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. (To enter the formula and still keep the selection active, click in the formula bar at the top of the screen and paste the formula there.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*To get Score, in **Cell F3** write this formula and fill 3 Row down:*

`=LARGE(B$3:B$6,ROWS(F$3:F3))`.

*To get Name, in **Cell G3** write this Array formula and fill down:*

**N.B.** Finish this Array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(A$3:A$6,SMALL(IF(B$3:B$6=F3,ROW(B$3:B$6)-ROW(F$3)+1),COUNTIF(F$3:F3,F3))),"")}
```

*To get order, in **Cell E3** write this formula and fill down:*

`=IFERROR(RANK(LARGE(B$3:B$6,ROWS(E$3:E3)),$F$3:$F$6),"")`

**How formula Works:**

- Formula in F3 finds top 3 Scores.
- Formula in G3 finds Names for Top 3 Scores, compares Score from
  Column F with Column B and pull name from column A
- Formula in E3 finds Rank for top 3 scores.

Comment: The formula in cell E3 should be `ROWS(E$3:E3)`, instead of `ROWS(E$3:E6)`. Also, I don't understand why you don't simply write `=RANK(F3;$F$3:$F$6)` in E3?

Comment: @piko, in fact I've calculated everything in context of TOP 3 Scores that i the prime reason I've calculated different. Modified to Rows($E3:E3),, was typo only. thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that the `RANK` function does the very same, without the need to add `LARGE` or `ROWS`. That's unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @piko, Yeah , y are write only rank can do also but since I'v wrapped with Large so I used like that only. To keep similarity in all 3 formulas.

Comment: RajeshS I agree with @piko that using the simpler `RANK()` formula is much better. The `G3` formula is hard enough for novice users to understand without unnecessarily complicating any of the other formulas. I see what you're saying, though. (Note that while your `G3` formula is the "standard" way of doing Top 3 Scores and can be more easily extended to more than 3 by simply filling down, my formula is easier for the novice to understand :-) ) Speaking of over complicating the formulas, it might be better if the `IFERROR()` was left out of the formulas, and a note added explaining its …

Comment: … potential usage. (For the specific example used it is completely superfluous and can possibly further confuse a novice.) Oh, and you forgot to include it in your `F3` formula ;-)

Comment: @robinCTS, #Piko, thanks for valuable suggestion, keep all this in mind for future.